# Laravel nested cross database relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, relation

Why set connection does not work in nested relation?

**Follower.php**

```
class Follower extends Model {
    $connection = 'followers';

    public function details() {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    } 
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model {
    $connection = 'users';

    protected $withCount = ['notifications'];

    public function notifications() {
        return $this->setConnection('followers')->hasMany('App\Models\Notifications');
    }
}
```

and the query:

```
Follower::query()->where('user_id', 1)->with('details')->get();
```

and it throws  :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'users.notifications' doesn't exist (SQL: select ` ....

But when I try this it works very well

```
User::with('notifications')->find(1);
```

**Update**
Notification.php

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'builder',
        'notification_type',
        'comment_id',
        'read_at'
    ];
}
```

Comment: user.php updated

Comment: @iamab.in still same result

Comment: your details method is missing closing inverted commas in user_id, is it a typo on stackoverflow or in code as well ??

Comment: @bhucho , oh sorry , code updated , that was a mistake on stackoverflow

Comment: can you add the `App\Models\Notifications` class?

Comment: @iamab.in updated

Comment: try setting connection name in `Notifications` class instead of relation.

Comment: added `protected $connection = 'followers';` still no luck

Comment: try removing `setConnection('followers')` from the relation `notifications()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219143/discussion-between-iamab-in-and-jackson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with laravel since 2018, for more information see this [thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23042) , also there is  a [open pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33755) to fix this issue and will get fixed till next release

for now you can use [hoyvoy/laravel-cross-database-subqueries](https://github.com/hoyvoy/laravel-cross-database-subqueries) package

install package using this

```
composer require hoyvoy/laravel-cross-database-subqueries
```

Follower.php

```
use Hoyvoy\CrossDatabase\Eloquent\Model;

class Follower extends Model {
    $connection = 'followers';

    public function details() {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    } 
}
```

User.php

```
use Hoyvoy\CrossDatabase\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {
    $connection = 'users';

    protected $withCount = ['notifications'];

    public function notifications() {
        return $this->setConnection('followers')->hasMany('App\Models\Notifications');
    }
}
```

for every model you have add the default `protected $connection`

Comment: i tried the package and it works Thank you , anyway i prefer to wait for next release instead of installing more packages